# How to support virtual hosts with OSGI HttpService

Tags: java, osgi

All examples of using an osgi `HttpService` show how to register servlets, resources, etc -- but all on the same service instance, and in the same namespace.

How can I run multiple instances of the `HttpService` in osgi (preferably embedded), each with its own namespace, based on HTTP requests received for a specific IP address or hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/osgi-http-service-utils/) that purports to allow starting multiple `HTTP Service`.

I've not used it but it might solve at least part of your query.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  I also found a great [blog post](http://www.codeaffine.com/2011/10/05/raprwt-osgi-integration-ii) explaining how to use a [ManagedServiceFactory](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/ManagedServiceFactory.html) with the ConfigurationAdmin service to instantiate multiple instances of HttpService along with an implementation's specific settings, which offers some good insight.