# OSGi HTTP Bundle - Bind to two ports

Tags: http, osgi, port, apache-felix

I'm using the Apache Felix HTTP Jetty bundle. I can start the servlet container / HttpService and assign it to a port using the system property

```
org.osgi.service.http.port=8080
```

But I would like to have two such services, bound to two different ports, eg my application API should be served on 8080, but some static web pages should be served on port 80.

- How can I start the HTTP service a second time on a different port?
- When registering servlets, how can I know which service is bound to which port?

Edit: for that last question, the service comes with the port value set in a property 
org.osgi.service.http.port: 8080

Answer (score 2):

If you switch over to Pax-Web you'll be able to do something like it. Pax-Web supports Virtual Hosts, and let's you bind a certain application to a single connection. Some more details on how to use it you'll find at my two blog posts:
[Bind web applications to specific http connectors - part 1](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2013/01/bind-certain-web-applications-to-specific-httpconnectors/)
[Bind web applications to specific http connectors - part 2](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2013/05/bind-certain-web-applications-to-specific-httpconnectors-ii/)

Comment: In Pax-Web, does using jetty connectors (to get multiple ports) require to have a full web application, or can I also just use a simple servlet registration in a HttpService?

Comment: You'll need the enhanced http service, the webcontainer service, so it most likely is best to have at least the whiteboard extender also running, makes your life easier with registering. See the second sample and especially the code-sample: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/whiteboard-extended/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/extender/samples/whiteboard/internal/Activator.java

Answer (score 1):

Felix http.jetty 3.2.6 provides a ManagedServiceFactory, which makes it easy to create multiple http instances with different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with the Http servers in OSGi I've worked with. Creating a little forwarder between the ports is of course quite easy to do in Java.

Comment: Bad news. I thought this was the usecase for the ManagedServiceFactory - so many services with differing configurations could be launched.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can if the Apache Felix HTTP Jetty bundle exposes a ManagedServiceFactory. (EDIT: It does not)

[How to support virtual hosts with OSGI HttpService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342560/how-to-support-virtual-hosts-with-osgi-httpservice)

http://www.codeaffine.com/2011/10/05/raprwt-osgi-integration-ii/

If I understand, the magic is in here:

http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r2/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html#createFactoryConfiguration(java.lang.String)

If you create and register a Configuration using the pid of the managed service factory, it will create a new instance of HttpService using a new Pid.

Comment: Though if Managed Service Factory services would be useful if you supported multiple Http Services, I can't find any doc that says the Apache Felix Http Jetty server supports this. And in my setup the metatype indicates that the configuration is a singleton, not a factory.

Comment: The project at eclipselabs (http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/osgi-http-service-utils/) looks promising... Will try it.

Comment: @PeterKriens You are correct Apache Felix HTTP Jetty bundle does not expose a factory pid.